# Were any real vehicles damaged colliding with model vehicles?

Tags: transportation, accidents

Vehicle accidents are one of the most dangerous aspects of modern life. **Model** vehicle accidents are usually a lot less dangerous, though there are a few [cases](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1447013/Girl-14-killed-by-model-plane-after-near-misses.html) of [fatalities](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2413231/Roman-Pirozek-Jr-Man-decapitates-remote-control-helicopter.html). Has a model vehicle ever directly damaged a real one? If so, which was the worst such incident?

Perhaps a model train or remote-control car could derail a train, but a collision between hobby aircraft (airplane, helicopter, or drone) and real aircraft seems more likely. Several experiments have sought to understand the damage airliners suffer in drone strikes, but a [publicized case in Mexico](https://petapixel.com/2018/12/14/737-passenger-plane-slams-into-drone-during-landing-reports-say/) was disproven; unless I am mistaken there have not yet not been any drone strikes on airplanes. I searched for some key phrases and only found mentions of collisions between pairs of model vehicles. Maybe someone else will have a better angle.